# Compound filters in Cognos 10.2

Tags: filter, cognos

I've encountered an interesting situation with Cognos Report Studio 10.2. I've written a simple report of employees with one report page and one query.

- Version 1 of the report uses eight individual filters (a=1, b=2, c=3, ...) and the output is **12,869** records.
- Version 2 is exactly the same as Version 1, except the eight filters are combined into one with a compound statement (a=1 AND b=2 AND c=3 AND ...), and the output is **12,010** records.

Logically, shouldn't they produce identical output?

Comment: Any chance you could show us the compound statement?  Even if you change the field names?

Comment: Here's the compound filter: [Filter](http://imgur.com/UlevWTE)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools - Show Generated SQL from both reports.  Compare the generated SQL using a tool like WinMerge (http://winmerge.org).  That should make the difference obvious.

If after looking at the difference between the queries the problem is not apparent, run the vendor specific SQL in your database and verify whether you get the same counts from the queryies as you do from the reports.

Comment: It shows a difference in the WHERE clause, which I'd expect, but why should the two reports, which are equivalent logically, produce different results?

Comment: Try running each query and verify that the counts are the same from the report.  If the counts are two different numbers, but each match 1 report, then you need to look more closely at the where clause.   If you want, post the two where clauses and I might be able to see the issue.